# Is there a way to find where other players are in the Minecraft world without asking them for their coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to find where other players are in the Minecraft world without asking them for their coordinates? I play with friends. We've sort of aligned ourselves in a 2 vs 2 match-up, and since we wanna PvP with them, we need to find them first.

Comment: there was a GPS-not-stalker-mod but it was updated to require consent before tracking you

Comment: A *stupid* way is to mark your coordinates, then `/tp` to other player, mark the coordinates and `/tp` back to your original coordinates. (Only if you are allowed to use `/tp`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not without mods (and even then this is functionality most modders don't care about creating). You're going to have to hunt them the old-fashioned way.

Look for signs of passage: half-harvested trees, temporary shelters, mined ore, cobblestone. Lay traps: place tempting things and wait in a camouflaged spot. Find their base(s).

Comment: Which mods would show me their locations? I heard Nodus works well for this application. Would you happen to know if this is true?

Comment: I don't know of any personally. I do know that to work everywhere on the server (i.e., outside of your personal chunk-loading radius) such a mod would have to be installed on the server.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can share a map item on a multiplayer server.

If you have a map, you can "clone" it to create an exact duplicate. It will show the same explored area on each clone, and **all players who are using the map can see player arrows for each other.** I have tested this with my brother on our server.

To clone a map, put the Map item to be cloned and one or more Empty Maps in the crafting grid. You will get 1 clone per Empty Map.

For more information, see: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map_(item)#Cloning

Comment: when you say "using" a map, do you mean they have to have it active in their hand?

Answer (score 5):

My Bukkit plugin [Mapcoords](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-mods/mapcoords/) has a command `/mc find [player]` that will tell you the coordinates of a player.

Comment: Welcome to the site! And thanks for disclosing your relationship to the mod. I formatted your post a bit just to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Best solution, Dynmap. Could keep it secret if you were to choose so (easily done simply by keeping the port secret or changing it if discovered). Cursor position displays location readout on the upper left of the screen. Shows all server worlds.

This is my server dynmap (copy & paste):

chunktvlive.com/minecraft

Have a look at it to get the feeling of how the plugin operates.

Here is the link to the Dynmap Bukkit page:

http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/dynmap/

And finally here's a great vid explaining how to setup and use:

Once installed and ready, you can basically customize it to almost as far extent as you could a website. Hope this could help!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, Chunk! This is a great answer but I've edited out your server IP as we try to avoid any and all promotional material on the site. We also don't use signatures/sign-offs, since your flare takes that job. I'd suggest putting your server IP in your profile instead, which is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer should be credited to @QbsidianH20 , but if you are op, or at the server console, you can use:

```
/tp <Player/Entity> ~ ~ ~ –
```

This is a teleport command. The tilde means relative, but with no additional values, it wont actually move them. It will however display their coordinates in the console.

Comment: This doesn't work, it teleported the player to the world spawn point instead of their current position.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a command solution, this works in vanilla Minecraft:

```
execute at [username] run tp @p ~ ~ ~
```

This will teleport the player to themselves, outputting the coordinates.

This is mostly unnoticeable, but **will dismount the player from any entities they are currently riding** (boats, minecarts, horses, etc.)